# No route found for "GET /login

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

When I try to login with wrong credentials it says "try again, wrong credentials", but after entering the correct credentials it gives error 
No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/bdayProj/web/app_dev.php/login"). Below is the configuration of my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

# http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
providers:
    in_memory:
        memory: ~

    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        logout:    true
        anonymous: true
        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: ~
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And my routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to specify the login path in your security file

This is an example :

```
 firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                login_path: fos_user_security_login
                check_path: fos_user_security_check
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: security.csrf.token_manager
                default_target_path: /
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Now when i click on logout it again ives me same error - No route found for "GET /" (from "http://localhost/bdayProj/web/app_dev.php/login")

Comment: do the same with logout :             logout:
                path:   /users/logout
                target: /

Comment: Just did that 

logout: 
                path: /users/logout
                target: /login

Gives error - You must activate the logout in your security firewall configuration

Comment: I just changed the logout: 
                path: /user/logout, to logout: 
                path: fos_user_security_logout .. it is working fine now.
The only issue left now is that the logout option seem to appear on the login page itself. How do you give the same logout link on the user homepage?

Comment: Well, i think you can do a if statment on your option. Check if the user is login with twig {% if app.user %} //display the logout option {% else %} //display the login option {% endif %}. Try to do something like this if you know what i mean, and tell me if its works :)

Comment: According to symfony doc, it's better to use {% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') %} than my solution just above

Comment: i simply used <a href="{{ logout_path('main') }}">Logout</a> in my index.html.twig file. seems to work fine. Since the homepage is supposed to be displayed whenever the user is logged in hence m guessing i may not need the if statement.

Comment: logout path ? is not a twig function no ? it's <a href="{{ path('my_path') }} no ?

Comment: m not sure, found it here [link] https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2014/10/06/symfony2-logging-out/

Comment: ive got another problem.. here is the link for it.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36715164/an-exception-occurred-while-executing-insert-into-events-user-id-et1-et2-va